# Robot in a grid - DS

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to solve below problem but I have no clue where to start..

There is robot and it needs to reach obstacle in a grid. The obstacle is denoted as 9 and the grid is 0/1 matrix. Robot can only travel on 1. Find the shortest path to get to obstacle. Robot is at (0,0) position

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is maze traversal with or without possible obstacles in the grid. A DFS search with marking visited positions and Dynamic Programming and Memoization would do the trick in the optimum way.

Its a common starter problem.

Comment: is there a similar problem in leetcode or other place?

Comment: I think you can search it up...Hackerrank.com has one and i have seen a similar problem in codingame.com ... advanced techniques on the same are like a* search and all..